# How to Organize Flask Functions for Blueprint/Methods/Routes

Tags: python, flask

I'm sure this question has been answered somewhere else but I keep searching every once in awhile and can't find a good answer. My Flask project is growing in size and I think it should be better organized than it is. I use the functional organization method, which I like but feel there's room for improvement:

```
yourapp/
    __init__.py
    forms/
    static/
    utils/
    templates/
        home/
        control_panel/
        admin/
    views/
        __init__.py
        user.py
        control_panel.py
        admin.py
        reviews.py
    models.py
```

Models is an example of a file that has grown rather unwieldy over time. It currently defines every table and database in a single file (it's over 5K lines) and most of my queries are defined there (but most logic on what to do with that data is elsewhere). Should the models file be split up into a package?

Secondly, each of the views has the route as well as application logic, which I'm beginning to think that application logic should be separated elsewhere but I don't know where. For example, in reviews.py, I have something like:

```
@reviewsbp.route('/preload_reviews', methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def preload_reviews():
    bc, ct_list, bt_list = create_cus_billtype_lists(None)
    csv_form = administrative_form.ReviewCSVImport()
    cform = invoicing_form.InvoiceTo()
    rbform = administrative_form.ReviewBatchForm()
    cform.customer_type.choices = [(k, k) for k in ct_list]
    cform.bill_type_select.choices = [(k,k) for k in bt_list]

    if cform.validate_on_submit() and rbform.validate() and csv_form.validate():
        try:
            import_d = process_review_import(cform, rbform, csv_form)
            return render_template('/reviews/import_csv_results.html',
                                   title='Import Results', import_d = import_d)
        except AppError as ae:
            flash(ae,'negative')
        except Exception as e:
            return render_template('error.html', message=e)

    return render_template('reviews/review_batch_import.html',
                           title="Review Batch Import", cform=cform,
                           bt_list = ','.join(bt_list), rbform=rbform,
                           csv_form = csv_form)

def process_review_import(cform, rbform, csv_form):
    extension = os.path.splitext(csv_form.csv_file.data.filename)[1]
    if extension.lower() != '.csv':
        flash('Only CSV Files allowed.', 'negative')
        return redirect('/reviews/preload_reviews')
    file_path = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix='.csv')[1]
    csv_form.csv_file.data.save(file_path)
    with open(file_path,'r') as f:
        import_d = parse_review_import_csv(f)

    validate_review_data(import_d)
    import_d = check_for_duplicates(import_d)
    import_d = save_review_data_to_db(cform, rbform, import_d)

    os.unlink(file_path)

    return import_d
```

There's several other functions to the above route to process the data. Where should those go? Is it best practice to keep them together with the route definitions or put them elsewhere. Over time, they may become common to other views, which suggests they should be stored elsewhere to at least prevent circular imports while also being easier to review published routes.

To recap:

1. How should the models.py file be organized for large projects (as separate files in a module)?
2. Should the queries be stored as a classmethod for each model or elsewhere?
3. The logic that processes the queried data, should that be stored in the model or with the other application logic?
4. Should the application logic be separated from where the routes (blueprints) are stored? If so, what is that commonly called?
5. How "skinny" should the routes be? Throughout the project there are many that are 20-30 lines doing something simple like a CRUD operation with all logic defined within the route.

Answer (score 1):

Effectively, Flask leaves this up to you. It's one of the strengths of the platform - in that it has fewer conventions, and far fewer opinions, than something like Django, for example, we comes almost pre-scaffolded.

At the risk of being unhelpful, you could comfortable answer 'it depends' but as a guide:

1. [Blueprints](https://exploreflask.com/en/latest/blueprints.html) are a way to organise your code in a similar way to
   Django's app pattern. You could imagine that a Blueprint could
   contain individual folders for models, views and routes specific to
   an 'app' which can be imagined as a collection of functionality. For
   example 'Users' could be a Blueprint/App.
2. That would likely be fine, and logical. It's good practice to keep
       data and the methods by which you attain that data first closely
       together.
3. This is your call and depends what your code is doing. `views.py` and
       `routes.py` are similar names, and you could split it out into
       `user/views.py` or `user/routes.py` if you want to. If you're just
       writing helpers or utilities, it can be helpful to have a `utils.py`
       or a `helpers.py` file next to wherever your routes are and then
       import the important classes or methods for a better structure and
       smaller overall files.
4. This is your call and depends what your code is doing. `views.py` and
       `routes.py` are similar names, and you could split it out into
       `user/views.py` or `user/routes.py` if you want to. If you're just
       writing helpers or utilities, it can  be helpful to have a `utils.py`
       or a `helpers.py` function couple wherever your routes are and then
       import the important classes or methods for a better structure and
       smaller files.
5. Your call - my advice is that if the route or view has logic that
   can be comfortable self contained, including any error handling, you
   want to keep in the route. If you're writing new logic or things you
   may want to reuse, jack them out into a `helper/util.py` and import it
   into one or many places.

Much of this is personal preference - but take a look at Django's structure. You won't want to recreate all of it but you might take some useful tips.